# How can I write a recursive Mongoose method?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a recursive data structure defined in MOngoDB/ Mongoose.

If I want to add a method to the resulting data object, it's as simple as:

```
FooSchema = {name:String, children:[{type:Schema.ObjectId}]};
FooSchema.methods.nonRecursiveMethod = function(){
    //Place code here
};
model.exports = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);
```

Issue:  How do I write such a method that needs to be recursive?  It needs to be able to call the resulting model object ('Foo') before it's been created.  E. G.

```
FooSchema = {name:String, children:[{type:Schema.ObjectId}]};
FooSchema.methods.nonRecursiveMethod = function(){
    Foo.where('_id').in(this.children).exec(function(err, results){
       results.forEach(function(item, index, array){ item.FooSchema });
    })
};
model.exports = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema); // Generates 'Foo' object
```

A sample operation might be where I need to destroy the parent node an all it's children nodes.  I want this logic to exist on the Foo object, because that's where it belongs, but...  How do I get it there?

Comment: "*call the resulting model object before it's been created*" - huh? Can you expand on that? And what exactly does this have to do with recursion? Would it be any different if the child nodes would be of another class, with another method to be invoked on them?

Comment: @bergi You create the actuall Foo objecgt on the last line, where you do `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);`.  That object isn't available before you create it, but you can't create it until you're done creating the schema...

Comment: I don't get it. Creating the schema does not include calling the method, does it? You're only *defining* the method, and for that you don't need any instances.

Comment: @Bergi I think I see what you're saying, and I'm just going to blame my C++ background.  I keep forgetting that methods aren't evaluated until they're called.  So I should be able to (for example) call `Foo = Mongoose.model('foo')` in the method to access the finished version.